# Screenshot the entire view being displayed in swift ui

Tags: ios, swift

I'm attempting to take a screenshot of my swift ui view and save it as a UIImage. The issue I've had is that it only takes a screenshot of the top layer (I have a video view from the back camera with an overlay over it, it only saves an image of that overlay).

```
private func captureScreenshot(of viewsToCapture: [UIView]) -> UIImage? {
    // Calculate the combined bounds of all views
    var combinedFrame = CGRect.zero
    for view in viewsToCapture {
        combinedFrame = combinedFrame.union(view.frame)
    }
    
    // Create a new context for the combined size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(combinedFrame.size, false, 0.0)

    // Iterate over views and capture their content
    for view in viewsToCapture {
        // Offset the view's frame to its position in the combined image
        let offsetFrame = view.frame.offsetBy(dx: -combinedFrame.origin.x, dy: -combinedFrame.origin.y)
        view.drawHierarchy(in: offsetFrame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }

    // Get the combined image
    let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return screenshot
}
```

This is the code I'm using

I tried changing the structure I use to take the image to combine a screenshot of the video view with the top view, but my app crashed whenever I tried that.